# Pandas groupby quantiles with indices

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following:

```
>>> numpy.random.seed(42)
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randint(0, 100, 19), columns=['val'], index=pandas.date_range('2021-03-01', '2021-03-04', freq='4H'))
>>> df
                     val
2021-03-01 00:00:00   51
2021-03-01 04:00:00   92
2021-03-01 08:00:00   14
2021-03-01 12:00:00   71
2021-03-01 16:00:00   60
2021-03-01 20:00:00   20
2021-03-02 00:00:00   82
2021-03-02 04:00:00   86
2021-03-02 08:00:00   74
2021-03-02 12:00:00   74
2021-03-02 16:00:00   87
2021-03-02 20:00:00   99
2021-03-03 00:00:00   23
2021-03-03 04:00:00    2
2021-03-03 08:00:00   21
2021-03-03 12:00:00   52
2021-03-03 16:00:00    1
2021-03-03 20:00:00   87
2021-03-04 00:00:00   29
>>> df.groupby(pandas.Grouper(freq='1D')).quantile(0.95, interpolation='higher')
            val
2021-03-01   92
2021-03-02   99
2021-03-03   87
2021-03-04   29
```

How can I also get the indices where quantiles are located within each group? I.e. my desired output is:

```
            val  idx
2021-03-01   92  2021-03-01 04:00:00
2021-03-02   99  2021-03-02 20:00:00
2021-03-03   87  2021-03-03 20:00:00
2021-03-04   29  2021-03-04 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of quantile calculate the `rank` within each group and figure out which values are `>=` your quantile (since you use `interpolate='higher'`). Then sort the DataFrame, keep only rows above your quantile and take the `first` within group. Assigning a column as the index brings this along.

```
m = df.resample('D')['val'].rank(method='dense', pct=True).ge(0.95)
df1 = df.assign(index=df.index)[m].sort_values('val')

df1.groupby(df1.index.normalize()).first()

            val               index
2021-03-01   92 2021-03-01 04:00:00
2021-03-02   99 2021-03-02 20:00:00
2021-03-03   87 2021-03-03 20:00:00
2021-03-04   29 2021-03-04 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason `df.assign(idx=df.index)[m].resample('D').min()` would not work?

Comment: Am I right that `sort_values(j)` is being negated by `resample('D')` afterwards? E.g. for `.ge(0.5)` (or any value <= 0.5, which is the rank of 51, timewise the first value for 2021-03-01) I get `2021-03-01 51 2021-03-01 00:00:00`. `pandas.DataFrame(numpy.arange(24, 0, -1), columns=['val'], index=pandas.date_range('2021-03-01', periods=24, freq='H')).sort_values('val').resample('D').first()` returns `2021-03-01 24`

Comment: @levantpied yes you seem to be correct. Instead of the resample methods I've changed it to use a normal groupby which doesn't negate the sort

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `groupby().transform`:

```
q95 = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D'))['val']
   .transform('quantile', q=0.95, interpolation='higher')
)
df[df['val']== q95]
```

Output:

```
                     val
2021-03-01 04:00:00   92
2021-03-02 20:00:00   99
2021-03-03 20:00:00   87
2021-03-04 00:00:00   29
```

Comment: Thanks! Am I right that this doesn't work when there are duplicates within groups (e.g. with `df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.tile(numpy.arange(3), 10)[0:19], columns=['j'], index=pandas.date_range('2021-03-01', '2021-03-04', freq='4H'))`)?